# Creating global collection and accessing it from all pages (C# Windows)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to have a global collection which I can access/edit on any page i.e `SpenderList`.

Here I have the instance of a `ObservableCollection` created in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace v003
{
    public sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Spender> SpenderList = new ObservableCollection<Spender>();

        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
        }
          ...

    }
}
```

When I type `SpenderList` on a page (`MainPage.xaml.cs`), the intellisense doesn't show that collection.

How do I access this collection from `MainPage.xaml.cs` and other pages?

Note: When I declared that instance in the `MainPage.xaml.cs`, all my subsequent codes work, so there's no issue with custom class, `Spender`.

Also I would like your opinion on this way of designing the app. Essentially all tasks are based on the items in this collection, and I'd want to any changes to this collection and its items performed from any page to be global.

Answer (score 3):

you need to cast:

```
 ((App)Application.Current).SpenderList
```

or make it static:

```
  public static ObservableCollection<Spender> SpenderList = new ObservableCollection<Spender>();
```

then you access it like this:

```
  App.SpenderList
```

Generally you should try to avoid globally accessible static variables.